# Combining multiple sheets from multiple excel files to one data frame

Tags: r, excel

I want to take the data from specific cells spread over two worksheets in one workbook, write it into one line on a new "consolidated" spreadsheet, and then repeat for all workbooks in said folder.

I'm struggling with pulling the specific cells and writing it to one line.

Cells D1, D4 and D7 need pulling on sheet 1, along with B4-F6 (rectangle) on sheet 2.

So far I can identify the correct folder, and also pull the data i need, however this is only for one named file at a time.

What I am unable to do is use read_xlsx across multiple sheets across multiple workbooks at once.

Grateful for any advice.

Some code i am (unsuccessfully) using below.

#### the following finds the folder

```
file.list <- list.files(path="FILE PATH", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

#### The following i can only work for one notebook at a time

Ideally i could use the "file.list" described above. Besides i can only pull a rectangle and not three specific cells without having the code repeated three times (which is not a problem if thats my only solution)

```
Info <- read_xlsx("FILE PATH", sheet = 1, range = "G6:G12",  col_names = FALSE,
col_types = "guess" ,  na = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0,
# n_max = Inf, guess_max = min(1000, n_max),
progress = readxl_progress(), .name_repair = "unique")

Amount <- read_xlsx("FILE PATH", sheet = 2, range = "D4:G6", col_names = FALSE,
col_types = "numeric" ,  na = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0,
# n_max = Inf, guess_max = min(1000, n_max),
progress = readxl_progress(), .name_repair = "unique")
```

and i'm having mixed success with lapply/sapply

Comment: It's helpful when you can specify what packages you're working with. I'm assuming `read_excel` is from `readxl`? What's your "mixed success" with `*apply` functions? If you're already using `readxl`, I'm guessing you might also be comfortable using some other tidyverse packages—I might try this with a list of sheet numbers and a list of ranges, then using `purrr::map2`

Comment: Mixed success with *apply either generates a long single column of all data from one sheet at a time, or colums each data next to each other, but still vertical (i am looking to switch from vertical to horizontal).

Comment: packages are tidyr, xlsx and readxl, but open to downloading anything. I'm not sure i would need more as readxl should read and write which is all i really want to do.